# ASP.NET MVC Core date only format is not working using DataAnnotation

Tags: asp.net-core, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Following `viewmodel` used in a view is supposed to display a StartDate as, say `9/30/2015`. But it is displaying as `9/30/2015 12:00:00 AM`. How can I make it display without time while **using** `DataAnnotaion`? I know I can use `@Model.StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyy")` inside view to display date only. But that would mean you have to do it in every view that is using the following `ViewModel`:

**ViewModel**:

```
...
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
...
```

**UPDATE**

The corresponding model class of the above `ViewModel` already has the following `DataAnnotation` that correctly creates the data type in SQL Server table as `Date`; and when you run a query on the corresponding table in `SSMS` it correctly displays the StartDate column's data with dates only, say, 9/30/2015 etc.)

**Model**

```
...
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
...
```

StartDate in the sql db is in fact `Date` only. Moreover, if I run a query on `SSMS` it correctly returns date only.

Comment: Have you tried just using the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch To answer your question, I've added an **UPDATE** section to my post. Moreover, I did try your suggestion on the ViewModel as well but to no avail.

Comment: Using the DataType attribute should work if your rendering with EditorFor or DisplayFor.

Comment: FYI, here's a fiddle that demonstrates https://dotnetfiddle.net/urdrHM

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch In my `view` I'm using `@Model.StartDate`. Per your suggestion I should be using `DisplayFor` instead - correct?

Comment: Probably.  If you just reference the variable, it's not going to use your data attributes.  You need to use DisplayFor or EditorFor to recognize them.  Otherwise you would have to do @Model.StartDate.Format("d")

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch But `@Model.StartDate` is still displaying the date except that it's including default time as well such `9/30/2015 12:00AM`. And `VS2017` does not recognize `@Model.StartDate.Format("d")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150435/discussion-between-nam-and-erik-funkenbusch).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem.  As per your comments, you are currently using `@Model.StartDate` to display a date.

You can either do this:

```
@Model.StartDate.ToString("d")
```

Or, you can use a model based approach in your ViewModel and do this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
```

Then, in your view use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StartDate)
```

Comment: Last comment that you added in our [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150435/discussion-between-nam-and-erik-funkenbusch) may answer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45382084/1232087). If you like you can write a response there and I'll mark that as an answer.