# Why this ASP.NET Core DataAnnotation works in ViewModel but not in Model alone

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, data-annotations

In my one ASP.NET Core app, a `View` is using following ViewModel. The underlying model of the ViewModel has an attribute `StartDate`. The model has `DataAnnotion` on `StartDate` but I'm not using the same `DataAnnotation` on the `StartDate` in `ViewModel` since I thought if `DataAnnotation` is in your Model then it gets aggregated to your `viewmodels`. And hence, the following `View` should display the `StartDate` as Date only. But the `View` is displaying `StartDate` as date and time, e.g. `9/30/2015 12:00:00 AM`. On the other hand if I use DataAnnotation `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` on `StartDate` attribute in the `ViewModel` as well, the `View` correctly displays the `StartDate` as date only, say, `9/30/2015`.

**Question**: Why `DataAnnotation` on the `Model` is not getting aggregated to `ViewModel`?

**Model**

```
...
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
...
```

**ViewModel**

```
...
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
...
```

**View**

```
...
@Html.DisplayFor(t => t.StartDate)
...
```

Comment: How the hell do you think that would be supposed to work? ViewModel and Model are **two completely different types**. There is no magic involved. An attribute is just that, a piece of meta data attached to an assembly, type, field, property or method, without **any functionality** on it's own. The attributes don't do anything unless some other piece of code reads these attributes and read their value or call the methods on them, nothing will ever happen

Answer (score 0):

Some DataAnnotations are used by MVC, some are used by EntityFramework (others are used by other frameworks, so it's not just EF and MVC). Some are used by both. For instance, [Required] is used by both EF and MVC, but for different reasons. EF uses it to mean non-nullable. MVC uses it to mean "requires a value in the textbox". However, the DataType attribute and many other types are MVC only. I know it's confusing, and there seems to be no good reference for which annotations are for which technology.

And this is a good reason why you need separate data models from view models. You may need a particular annotation on your data model (like [Required]) but don't want it in your ViewModel (because you want to accept no value in a field, and supply the value in a code-behind, for instance...